# Google Play Store not showing right number of downloads

Tags: android, google-play

I distributed some promo codes (200 codes) for my app in Google play Store. In the analytics report it shows `160 new users` and in promotion section of developer console it shows `160/200 codes` redeemed but the number of downloads show in console changed only by 9. Is there something wrong with downloads calculation in Play Store? or promo code downloads are not counted?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Store statistics are not updated real time. Wait for a day or two till you see near real figures. Also, they will never match exactly with the figures in your analytics reports.